# CoffeeScript variable scoping and inheritance in Meteor > 1.0

Tags: oop, meteor, coffeescript

I couldn't find anything about using `@(this)` to make variables global in official Meteor documentation of CS package.

1. Is it deprecated in new versions? Should we only use `shared` variable now?
2. Why haven't they also supported something like node.js `require` beside their smart packages and smart import policy?
3. If someone wants to write an OOP code by Coffee he should expose all classes to whole application. or he should make a costume package.
   are there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started working with Meteor, and since I work with CoffeeScript too, I've also had issues with scoping.

Having two scripts, `client.coffee` and `server.coffee`. I've declared a collection in `server`, that should have been autopublished, and accessible from `client` too. Because of scoping, my `collection` variable wasn't visible outside of `server.coffee`.

**In CoffeeScript, you can write "pure JavaScript"!**

```
localCollection = new Mongo.Collection 'MyCollection' # this is not accessible outside of server.coffee

`globalCollection = localCollection;` # this, however, is...
```

In CoffeeScript, everything that is enclosed in backticks is considered just JavaScript. The parser will take it as it is and put it into it's correct place in the resulting JavaScript file. Thanks to that, it won't generate `var globalCollection;` at the beginning of the file, and thanks to that the variable goes to [package, or global scope](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/namespacing).

**Also...**
Packages have [export](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_export), and there is also the the [share object](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/coffeescript). I've tried both, but somehow I couldn't get them to work. I'm really new to Meteor, haven't played with these two things extensively yet...

Comment: Didn't answer my question. I still can't figure out why they haven't used require I understand meteor has a different philosophy but lacking a require method means we can't have a proper modular design.